# Do other designers use software to slice their graphics?

Tags: software-recommendation, slices

I like to make graphics for apps. I generally start with Illustrator and move to Photoshop for some little finishing touches. I then save all of the assets as .png files to be used by the developer. (This is a process to say the least, especially with all of the resolutions required for Android)

Now, Slicy exports PSD elements as assets for your website or app, you just rename your layer groups once and let Slicy do everything else. Cut&Slice me does similar but for Windows.

Do other designers use this software or similar? If so, why? If not, why?

[Slicy website](http://macrabbit.com/slicy/)

[Cut&Slice me website](http://www.cutandslice.me/)

Comment: Hi Jenna, this seems like a pure shopping list question which is generally too broad and opinion-based to be helpful to anyone.

Comment: Hey Scott, sorry ill edit tomorrow when I'm back at ny laptop. Is it ok to ask for comparisons between specific products?

Comment: Have you looked into Generator? It's built into Photoshop CC: http://blogs.adobe.com/photoshopdotcom/2013/09/introducing-adobe-generator-for-photoshop-cc.html

Comment: Maybe an update could be in order, I'm using CS5.5. It looks great though.

Comment: I'm sure people do. Most web app work, however, for me at least, tends to be sprite-based. So I maintain one larger file rather than sliced individual files. When I do need separate files, I've found that--maybe out of habit more than anything--I'm fairly adept and cutting and pasting into separate files for export.

Comment: I haven't heard of many people using that kind of software, but it was obviously invented for a reason!  I would do as DA01 does and make larger files (not necessarily sprite sheets all the time) then I would make an action in photoshop to resize and save it the 3 or 4 times for Android and iOS